# Thinking Sphinx :sort_mode => :time_segments or :sort_mode => :expr with @weight*created_at?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm studding sphinx and thinking-sphinx and I need your opinion and help, what I want to do is the following:

I have a list of news (noticias) and I want to order the results by date and relevance because if I search for something doesn't matter when the news was created the query won't take in consideration. If I could specify at least that the closer year or year and month have more relevance my question should already be solved.

I saw a lot of things but not to much conclusive, maybe for my low experience with sphinx and thinking-sphinx.

How can a solve this problem? How you think is the best way? Thanks.

My model:

```
define_index do
  indexes :titulo
  indexes :chamada
  indexes :texto
  indexes :description
  indexes :keywords
  indexes :otimizador_de_busca
  indexes :created_at, :sortable => true
  indexes tags.nome, :as => :tag
  indexes usuario.nome, :as => :autor
  where "validacao = '1'"
end
```

My search function on controller:

```
termo = params[:termo].first(50)
@noticias = Noticia.search termo,
:field_weights => {:tag => 150, :autor => 120, :titulo => 100, :chamada => 80, :otimizador_de_busca => 65, :description => 50, :keywords => 50, :texto => 10},
:match_mode => :all,
:page => params[:pagina],
:sort_mode => :extended,
:order => "@relevance DESC, created_at DESC",
:per_page => 15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to note. Firstly, there's a difference between fields and attributes with Sphinx, and there's not really much to be gained by having created_at as a field, but it's far more useful as an attribute (which are natively sortable). So, let's update the index definition:

```
define_index do
  indexes :titulo
  indexes :chamada
  indexes :texto
  indexes :description
  indexes :keywords
  indexes :otimizador_de_busca
  indexes tags.nome, :as => :tag
  indexes usuario.nome, :as => :autor

  has :created_at

  where "validacao = '1'"
end
```

And then run `rake ts:rebuild` so that change is reflected in your index files and the Sphinx daemon is aware of it too.

As for how you're sorting... you've got a few options. In your example, you're sorting primarily by relevance, but anything with matching relevance scores has the newer items listed first. I think that'll work quite well.

If you want to use Sphinx's time_segments sorting, then that might also work well, as it'll group results first by their age (without being too specific), and then automatically orders within each age group by relevance:

```
termo = params[:termo].first(50)
@noticias = Noticia.search termo,
  :field_weights => {:tag => 150, :autor => 120, :titulo => 100, :chamada => 80, :otimizador_de_busca => 65, :description => 50, :keywords => 50, :texto => 10},
  :match_mode    => :extended,
  :page          => params[:pagina],
  :sort_mode     => :time_segments,
  :order         => :created_at,
  :per_page      => 15
```

I've also changed the match mode to extended, which I'd generally recommend.

Finally, as you've suggested, you could factor in the created_at timestamp with the relevance in an expression - that's up to you. There's probably formulas out there that could help with that, but I think that's extra complexity you probably don't need.

If you think that it's more important to have newer results first, then use time segments. If you think that it's more important to have relevant results to the search query first, use the extended sort mode in your own example. I think that one is better, but it's up to you.

Comment: Thank you so much Pat you really took out some doubts and this time_segments sort mod fits perfectly.
Do you know what I have to do to use the same script of time_segments but still match some field (why not try @weight + views someday? hahaha) like Pete Spicer says in this discussion: [link](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=3537)
I don't know how to do this using thinking-sphinx, so have you write already something about it or do you have some tutorial for I follow? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I can't positive you because my account is new but thanks a lot.

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer though? Also: to use what Pete Spicer suggests, pass in his long expression (IF...) as a string to :order, and set :sort_mode to :expr.